# Stop MySQLdb from crashing

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using MySQLdb to connect to a database to run queries. However, if the password is incorrect or MySQLdb fails to connect to the database, the script stops running. Instead, I would simply like to receive an error message as a string, and then continue with the script (as the completion of the queries is not essential to the other parts of the script). Is this possible?

Comment: @shadyabhi Sorry, it's just the generic connect() function of MySQLdb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script stops running because the `.connect()` call raises an exception.

You can *catch* that exception with a `try:`, `except:` handler:

```
import MySQLdb

try:
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(...)
except MySQLdb.Error as ex:
    print "The connection failed: {}".format(ex)
```